# How to remove bash key binding "x\000": self-insert

Tags: bash, bind

bash -p shows

```
"x\000": self-insert
```

May be that this came in by a typo.

In order to repair, a normal bind command

```
bind "x":self-insert
```

or

```
bind '"x":self-insert'
```

has no effect. Therefore I try to remove the false binding by

```
bind -r "x\000"
```

It does effect nothing.

I have tried all variations with  quotes and backslashes and $'\x00' and the like ('\0'), e.g.

```
bind -r "x"'\0'
```

without succsess.

But this was the solution --,for the first time:

```
bind -r ' "x" "$(echo -n -e "\x00")" '
```

For a second equal case this did not work.

The second case was because the normal command

```
bind '"x":self-insert'
```

caused again that bash -p shows

```
"x\000": self-insert
```

Is there really no unmistakenp way?

=====

== edit 08.12.2022 16:05

Thanks, but I need a way not to close the shell in order not to loose things.

. inputrc or other initiating files are not affected.

With my solution presented in the answer the unwanted binding is removed succsessfully.

The question now is how to make a new correct binding.

Even

```
bind "$(echo -n -e "\0170")":self-insert
```

is no wsy. All what I do results in

bash -p shows

```
"x\000": self-insert
```

I cannot ask you to help because you do not have such a corrupted shell.

( I do not have the courage to speculate if this is another craziness of bash )

Regards

Anton Wessel

Comment: If there is an unwanted binding in some interactive shell, then closing the shell and opening a new one may help and it's the easiest solution. If the unwanted binding affects the new shell, it means the binding is in `~/.inputrc` or (as `bind …`) in `~/.bashrc` or so (or in one of their global counterparts in `/etc`). In this case you probably want to fix the responsible file rather than `bind -r` in just one shell, because `bind -r` only affects the shell you run it from and does not affect the permanent config.

Comment: Other things to try next time: use the quoted-insert char (C-q or C-v) before typing x to get it taken literally. Or switch off  readline with `set +o emacs +o vi`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to is

```
bind -r "x" "$(echo -n -e "\x00")"
```

The problem why

```
 bind '"x":self-insert'
```

caused again that bash -p shows

```
"x\000": self-insert
```

is not yet solved. The reason is that I have not in this command to type "x" literally but in octal or decimal (in hex it cannot work because there "x" is involved).

I am trying how to insert "x" in decimal.

Comment: The output of a command doesn't have to be a syntactically correct input to the shell command interpreter. Consult bash(1) (`man bash`).